# Promise, fetch, codestyle. Please, explain .then(checkStatus).then(parseJSON)

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I have test code!

```
function checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
}
function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json()
}
```

I can write like here:

```
function load(id) {
    return fetch('/api/test/'+ id + '/', {method: 'get'})
                .then(response => checkStatus(response))
                .then(response =>  parseJSON(response))
                .catch(error=>console.error(error))
```

or I can write like there:

```
function load(id) {
    return fetch('/api/test/'+ id + '/', {method: 'get'})
                .then(checkStatus)
                .then(parseJSON)
                .catch(error=>console.error(error))
```

Please explain second variant. How does it `.then(checkStatus)
.then(parseJSON)` work?
I just write the reference to the functions, and not run it.

Answer (score 3):

`.then` takes functions as its arguments ... it calls the function passing in a single argument that is the resolved value of the promise

so think of

```
return fetch('/api/test/'+ id + '/', {method: 'get'})
.then(checkStatus)
```

as

```
return fetch('/api/test/'+ id + '/', {method: 'get'})
.then(function(resultOfPromise) {
     return checkStatus(resultPromise);
})
```

> By the way, this isn't limited to promise/then type code ... consider the following

```
function doThings(p1) {
    console.log(p1);
    return 'good bye';
}
setTimeout(doThings, 1000, "hello world");
```

> same concept - except that the the value returned by the callback in setTimout is ignored. In `.then()` however, the value returned by the callback is used as the resolved value of a Promise ... which is basically how promise chaining works (this is an over simplified explanation)

Comment: @oksana however, there is subtle diff between two variant on what ```this```  will point to inside the function you're passing to ```then```

Comment: @balajisoundar - that's why I used the phrase *think of* `A` *as*  `B`. Rather than saying `A` *is just like* `B`